# I want to check if the gpu is being used in tensorflow version 1

Tags: python, tensorflow

The gpu is still below 5%, is there any code to check if the model is using the gpu?
(Tensorflow 1.15)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snippet to tell Tensorflow to use GPU

```
import tensorflow as tf 
if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
  print('Default GPU Device:{}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))

else:
  print("Please install GPU version of TF")
```

**Output**

```
Default GPU Device:/device:GPU:0
```

If you would like a particular operation to run on a device of your choice instead of what's automatically selected for you, you can use with `tf.device` to create a device context, and all the operations within that context will run on the same designated device.

```
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)

# Place tensors on the CPU
with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
  a = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
  b = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])

# Run on the GPU
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
print(c)
```